# Why can't Hudson access my 'srcsafe.ini' file?

Tags: hudson, visual-sourcesafe, jenkins

I'm trying to configure the Hudson VSS Plugin to access a particular Sourcesafe repository to retrieve files and for polling.

I know I've got the proper information configured on the fields for the plugin, but I'm still getting access errors.

Can anyone offer suggestions as to what might be the problem with my setup? (I've already done as much trouble-shooting as I can..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my access issues by configuring Hudson to run under a named user account rather than the Local System Account.

I had actually done this with the intention of mapping my SourceSafe share as a drive and then using that information in the VSS plugin configuration (I needed a named user for this since mapped drives aren't shared between users and are not available to the Local System Account), but once I started running the Hudson service under the named account, I was able to access my srcsafe.ini file without any issues.

NOTE: You'll also want to grant the named user account access to the Hudson/Jenkins directory via the Security tab on the folder properties. For my builds, I also had to give access to the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' folder based on what I was compiling.